# Configure multiline autocompletion in TeXStudio

Tags: texstudio, auto-completion

I would like to configure a longer completion in TeXStudio, like this one:

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    \caption{}
    \label{tab}
    \begin{tabular}{lcS[table-format = -1.3e0]p{0.25\columnwidth}}
        \toprule

        \midrule

        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

I found the `cwl` files on my computer and [online](http://svn.code.sf.net/p/texstudio/code/trunk/completion/). However, there is no example to configure a longer auto-completion. Can you give me an example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use a TeXstudio macro for something like this.

1. Go to <kbd>Macros</kbd> ⇒ <kbd>Edit Macros...</kbd>.
2. Click <kbd>+ Add</kbd>.
3. Enter a name, e.g. `My table`. This will appear in the macros menu.
4. Enter a trigger. I like to use things like `MYTABLE`, which you’re unlikely to use as normal text. When you type this trigger anywhere in your document, it will be replaced by your table template. You can use about anything here, e.g. `I want a table, editor!`.
5. Finally, paste your table template in the field “LaTeX Content” and click <kbd>OK</kbd>.

Now, your template will be pasted whenever you type `MYTABLE`. Alternatively, you can press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F1–9</kbd>, according to the number of the macro you want to use.

If you want to learn more about what you can do with macros in TeXstudio, check out [section 4.5 *Personal Macros*](http://svn.code.sf.net/p/texstudio/code/trunk/utilities/usermanual_en.html#SECTION33) in the TeXstudio user manual. With JavaScript, you can do much more complex stuff than pasting text.

Comment: Wonderful! Where are these macros saved? I would like to copy them to other TeXstudio installations.

Comment: The shortcuts `%<some text%>` can be very helpful which will be turned into jump marks that can reached by using `Ctrl`+`Left` and `Ctrl`+`Right` (one for the caption, one for the label, one for the head and one for the body of the tables).

Comment: @Dirk On Windows 7, they’re in `C:\Users\doncherry\AppData\Roaming\texstudio\texstudio.ini` – look for the lines starting with ``Macros\``[a number]`=`.

Comment: Thank you! @doncherry What is the advantage to use the trigger instead of the abbreviation? With this it should be possible to use Strg+Space to get the macro, isn't it?

Comment: @Dirk I don’t have much experience with the “abbreviations”, but it looks like they have to look like a LaTeX macro, i.e. start with a `\`. They’ll show up in the normal autocomplete box, but once selected, they are replaced with the macro text. I just find the trigger text (which actually is a regular expression) more convenient because I don’t need the backslash, but either way works fine.

Comment: The advice to start the abbreviation with a backslash was very good! First I only took text and TeXstudio does not react on my second macro by the abbreviation. Now it does.