# Subcaption cannot be found by MiKTeX package manager?

Tags: packages, subcaption

Even though I cannot find it with the pacakage manager,  a file with `\usepackage{subcaption}` in preambles can be complied successfully.

Besides, the command `\begin{subfigure}...\end{subfigure}` cannot be recognized by TeXstudio, after I have manually added `subcaption.cwl` into the completion files.

Answer (score 2):

Package `subcaption` is part of package `caption`as you can see by invoking `texdoc caption`. Then you get the pdf documentation for `caption` and `subcaption`.

I do not use TeXStudio, so I can't help you with your second question. Can the manual of TeXStudio help? Or perhaps the question [configure-multiline-autocompletion-in-texstudio](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121147/configure-multiline-autocompletion-in-texstudio)?